# L2 regularization and its intuition

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, intuition

I am reading about L2 Regularization. As far as I know we add a thing to the loss function that:
$$J(w) = LOSS + \lambda w^T w$$

In the book Deep Learning by Goodfellow et al., they stated "minimizing J(w) results in a choice of weights that make a tradeoff between fitting the training data and being small".

$w^T w$. How is this related to "being small"? Why the weights now tend towards zero rather than any other values?

Comment: [Many duplicates in this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regulari*+intui*+++answers%3A1).

Comment: I just have a quick look at the list. Most of the post it seems like it explains regularization, but what I want to know is how $w^t w$ mathematically does with regularization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w^t w$ term can be written as:

$$
w^t w = \sum_j w_{j}^2
$$

This becomes smaller when $w_j$ is closer to zero.
That is why the weight tend to be close to zero due to the regularization term.

Answer (score 1):

The $w^Tw$ is a quadratic function with minimum at $0$. If the $w$ is "big" (in term of its distance from origin), the $\lambda w^Tw$ term grows and make loss bigger.As we are trying to minimize the loss, we will prefer $w$ to be small (i.e. closer to origin).